# c# stateless random selection of orders with predefined probability

Tags: c#

**Scenario:**

Multiple agents process orders simultaneously. Orders are not shared between agents. Each agent is assigned a sampling percentage. Let say agent A has sampling percentage of 10% and B has 20%. Both process 100 orders each. We want to audit around 10 orders from A and 20 from B.

Orders are received in a continuous flow. It is important to make QC or not to QC decision right away (as soon as agent finishes his/her work). If an order is to be audited it moves to QC queue.

**Chosen Solution (there are several):**

Audit orders with probability pct/100 where pct is sampling percentage assigned to agents. For A it will 0.1 and B it will be 0.2

**Problem:**

We can use Random.NextDouble() method and check number is less than or equal to 0.1 for agent A. However, the best practice is to use same ***instance*** of `Random` object to generate numbers. That is not possible in this case because the application might be closed and opened several times a day. Also, an order can take more than a day to process.

How can we ensure that orders selected for QC are approximately 10% for A and 20% for B after a sufficiently large number of orders are processed (let say 40 or 50)?

Comment: What has "the application might be closed and opened several times a day" got to do with the question?

Comment: Have you tested this and/or read the documentation?

Comment: @Enigmativity, best practice of Random class usage suggests that we use it one instance to generate a sequence of random numbers. Using new instance every time does NOT guarantee randomness. If program is closed, it is going to have a new instance even if I maintain a static single instance of Random object.

Comment: @RaviMPatel - That's only **potentially possible** if you create two instances of `Random` within about 16ms of each other. Opening and closing the app certainly won't cause that.

Comment: @Enigmativity, oh ok. Is it theoretically accurate to use new random object for each agent? Will it select order with desired probability?

Comment: @RaviMPatel - Yes, using `Random` would generally be sufficient in this circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what the default constructor of random does.

The problem arises when you new up new instances of random in loops or in multi-threaded situations.

```
public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount) {}
```

Basically it uses the [Environment.TickCount Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.8) to seed the generator:

> Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started.

So it's not perfect, but it's pretty good. However, on saying this, `Random` isn't all that random anyway and it has biases; if you want a better random number generator, and less chance of resolution problems, uses a cryptographic random number generator with an appropriate seed.

Comment: Is it theoretically accurate to use new random object per agent per order selection? Will it select orders with desired probability over the period of time? If not, could you provide a code sample for cryptographic random number generator?

Comment: @RaviMPatel it will most likely be good enough for you to use, the biases or tiny and should only matter in certain situations, like cryptography